# Are there any universally accepted icons for Gold, Silver, and Bronze?

Tags: shapes, icon, symbolism, accessibility

This is an [additional question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/130881/what-can-we-do-to-make-stack-exchange-badges-inclusive) to one which I had asked on UXSE for making the Badges inclusive by providing unique icons for Gold, Silver, and Bronze Badges.

Are there any universally accepted icons of the same?

Comment: If there were clear-cut, distinct, universal delineations, then you'd be able to tell a bronze badge from a gold one when presented by the various Stack Exchange sites ;-) To this day I cannot tell whether I won a bronze or gold without looking it up…</joke rant>

Answer (score 1):

[A simple internet search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=gold%20silver%20bronze%20icon&iar=images&iax=images&ia=images) will tell you no, there aren't universal icons for these 3 badges / tiers. Some will use stars, some will use coins, others will use other shapes depending on: context the icons are being used for, style, preference, etc.

The one (sort of) consistent element is color: yellow-ish for gold, some shade of gray for silver and a shade of orange  for bronze.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Usually it's the same shape in different color. In real-life, it's the same object moulded from different material and the same logic applies to the icons. There's no distinct gold badge shape and so on.